# Creating a stampfile folder

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a folder that's using a timestamp as reference. So the code its like this. But its not creating the folder.

```
$date=(Get-Date).ToString('dd-MMMM-yyyy')
 $regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]
write-host "FUNCION LIMPIA ARCHIVO $archivo" -fore white 

   $a = get-content $root\UNB\TMP\$archivo |
    foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^[ .!pÿ>i@]{1,}', '') } |
    Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^[p ÿÿ@]{1,}', '') } |
    Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^[!!  !           ]{1,}', '') } |
    Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^0 {2,}', '') } |
    Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '>', '') } |
    Foreach-Object { ($_.TrimEnd() )}  | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} |
    set-content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$date\$archivo
```

Comment: on win7ps5.1, the `Set-Content` cmdlet does not create new directories. it MAY do so on win10, but i can't find any info on that. you will need to use `New-Item` to create new directories.

Comment: Removed tags from title; spelling; grammar; noise reduction.